# Why does 3 > 2 > 1 return false while 1 < 2 < 3 returns true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why does `3>2>1` return `false` while `1 < 2 < 3` returns `true`?

```js
console.log(1 < 2 < 3);
console.log(3 > 2 > 1);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since `1 < 2` evaluates to `true` and `3 > 2` evaluates to `true`, you're basically doing :

```js
console.log(true < 3);
console.log(true > 1);
```

And `true` is converted to `1`, hence the results.

Comment: See also [MDN: Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for operator precedence and associativity.

Answer (score 11):

Because it interprets left to right and because it tries to cast to same type.

`1 < 2 < 3` becomes `true < 3`, which because we are comparing numbers is cast to `1 < 3` which is truth.

`3 > 2 > 1` becomes `true > 1`, which because we are comparing numbers is cast to `1 > 1` which is false.

Answer (score 8):

That is because it is evaluated from left to right, making it equivalent to the below commands:

```js
console.log(true < 3);
console.log(true > 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Operator "<" and ">" Associativity is left-to-right** so

Check below link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

console.log(1 < 2 < 3) ==> console.log(true < 3)==> (**true means 1**)=> console.log(1 < 3);
**Answer is true**

console.log(3 > 2 > 1) ==> console.log(true >1)==> (**true  means 1**)=> console.log(1 >1);
**Answer is false**

console.log(3 > 2 >=1) ==> console.log(true >=1)==> (**true means 1**)=> console.log(1 = 1);
**Answer is true**

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will read like this
`$console.log((1 < 2) < 3)`
and `$ console.log(( 3>2 ) > 1)`

in 1st case: `$ console.log(1 < 2 < 3)`
first compiler execute 1<2 which returns 1(true), after that it goes like 1<3 which is again 1(true). hence overall it is true.

execute 2nd one with same logic, it will gives you false.